# Clarification re: Vue.js actions/mutations

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need some clarification re: the interplay between these functions. I'm following a Vue.js tutorial and we have an action that commits a mutation.

Action:

```
updateUser({commit}, user) {
  commit('setUser', {userId: user['.key'], user})
}
```

Mutation:

```
setUser(state, {user, userId}) {
  Vue.set(state.users, userId, user)
}
```

My question is about the order of arguments in the `commit()` call in the action. The payload is an object with a userId as its first name-value pair, and its second value is the user object itself. Now, in the mutation definition, the values in the payload the mutation is expecting are reversed. I can't imagine how JavaScript/Vue would know what types of data to expect in the `setUser` definition so that the order of the name-value pairs in the expected payload wouldn't matter. So why does the app still work? Is the mutation expecting to receive variables called `user` and `userId`, and that's why the order doesn't matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with Vue but a [Javascript destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) syntax; The order doesn't matter because it's extracting value from object by keys; in your case, `setUser` is expecting an object that contains a key `user` and a key `userId` which is passed down by the `updateUser` action; Also notice this is just a syntax sugar that you don't necessarily have to follow, that is, you can write your mutation that accepts a normal object as parameter as follows:

```
setUser(state, obj) {
  Vue.set(state.users, obj.userId, obj.user)
}
```

Comment: Oh my! I'd forgotten about destructuring and was seeing it as just an object. Thanks very much for the clarification.